# Can I make a WooCommerce shortcode from variable template part?

Tags: templates, woocommerce, shortcode

I want to create a shortcode that will show the template parts `mytheme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php` on my Woocommerce product page where I want. My target is to set my page fully from WP Barkery on Long Description and not call this template part from templates files.

I made :

```
function shortcode_add_to_cart_variations(){
    wc_get_template_part( 'single-product/add-to-cart/variable' );
}
add_shortcode('add-to-cart-variations', 'shortcode_add_to_cart_variations');
```

The template part is called but the variations it's not shown because `$available_variations = NULL` : https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.5.0/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php#L26

How can I make my shortcode and show variations where I want on my product page (for example in my Revolution Slider)?

Answer (score 0):

I found myself the answer.

I only need to use the core woocommerce function `woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart()`

Detail here: http://hookr.io/functions/woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart/

Add this in my functions.php (child theme) :

```
    function shortcode_add_to_cart_variations(){
        woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart();
    }
    add_shortcode('add-to-cart-variations', 'shortcode_add_to_cart_variations');
```